# Validating two fields to avoid duplication in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, validation

I have users form  where user updates their basic details like email, mobile number etc. When user updates their information then I first want to check whether modified data already available or not in datbase (suppose if he modifies his mobile number then it should check first that the newly entered numbered is already use by some other user). If it is available then it shows popup indicating number already used. And if it is unique number then it will update. I have used following code to check condition & then decide whether to perform update function or not.

On Update Click

```
string mobile = string.Empty;
string emailID = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mobileNo.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Text)) {
    string str = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @email or mobile = @mobile and not ID = @ID";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobileNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", psNo.Text);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) {
        mobile = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("mobile");
        emailID = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("email");
        if (mobile == mobileNo.Text) {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Mobile No Already Exist');</script>");
        } else {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Email ID Already Exist');</script>");
        }
    } else {
        this.updateContactInfo();
    }
}
```

This code works but not completely. Suppose if user changes their mobile number & keep their old email address then too it shows email already exist. How I can structure my query that it should check all rows except user who has logged in.

Comment: If I use unique key or primary key then too it won't solve because in that too it will check all rows including user who is logged in currently & if someone only want to change their mobile number not email then it still show email already exist & only mobile number will not be updated